# Center C# form on secondary screen

Tags: c#, forms, location, center, screens

Quick question, hopefully an easy fix.
I am kinda new to C# and am trying to center a second form, on the secondary screen when it opens. So far I can get it to open on the second screen no problem but it sits in the top left and I cant get it to center. I am aware of the fact that the `Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;` will put it in the top left part of said working area. I was wondering if there is a way to (essentially) change the `.Location` to something else that will center regardless of actual screen size? This will be going onto multiple different systems with varying screen sizes. 
Here is the code that I have so far.

On the first form.

```
public partial class FrmPrompt : Form
{
    public FrmPrompt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButNo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmConfirm confirm = new frmConfirm();
        Screen[] screens = Screen.AllScreens;
        lblConfirmMsg.Text = "Please Wait For Customer To Confirm...";
        butContinue.Hide();
        confirm.Show();
    }
}
```

On the second form:

```
public partial class frmConfirm : Form
{
    public frmConfirm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Location = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did [Form.CenterToScreen()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.centertoscreen.aspx) not do what you wanted?

Comment: if you read what is written there, you will see _Do not call this directly from your code_ remark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CenterScreen` will locate Form on **current** screen, so if your `FrmPrompt` on second screen, when you clicking `ButNo` - this will work. But I think this is not you asking for.

More then that, `CenterScreen` **will overwrite** any location setting of your from Location that was setted **before** Show method invocation. So I suggests to override OnShown method of `frmConfirm`

```
protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnShown(e);
    var area = Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea;
    var location = area.Location;

    location.Offset((area.Width - Width) / 2, (area.Height - Height) / 2);
    Location = location;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! been looking for this for ages. Great help!

Answer (score 1):

try this on the first form, no need to set anything in the 2nd form.

```
        //put it after this line: frmConfirm confirm = new frmConfirm();
        confirm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
```

Comment: if you set `StartPosition` to `CenterScreen` then form `Location` **will be overwritten** on Show method invocation.

Comment: That just centers the 2nd form on the primary display. I need it to center on the secondary display.